# traaversing a listview and saving data of any view which is checked

Tags: android

hey i have created a listview and using custom ArrayListAdapter and overridding the getView() method. i have a save button to save data from listview items which are checked . as they contain checkbox. Now the problem is when i save data using getchildCount method to loop each item(Row,Child) it only traverse to the visible items. if i use getCount() method it gives NullPointerexception as it is not considering the items which are not visible . i know i have to use my adapter to do all this but how???????????
this is my class using adapter adapter--------------

```
package com.bmi.cal.hitesh;
```

public class BreakFast extends Activity  {

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finish();
    db.close();
}
float cal_needed=0;
public int counter =0,listItemCount=0,flag=1;
TextView tv_cal_count;
CheckBox        check;
public ListView         list;
ContentValues   values = new ContentValues();
SQLiteDatabase  db;
List<Employer>  data = new ArrayList<Employer>();
Cursor          cur,cur2;
String          type, title,form,descr,tv_cal_str;
int calories;
private Button done;
private TextView tv_cal_needed;
private String cust;
 int temp_diet_id[]= new int[234];
//final String CREATE_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Bfast_table (" + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + "diet TEXT,calories INTEGER,type INTEGER);"; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         final String MYPREFS = "mySharedPreferences";
         SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS,0);
        list= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv_cal_count = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_cal_count);
        tv_cal_needed = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_calories);
        check = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("bmi.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null );
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        cust = mySharedPreferences.getString("txt_cust", null);
        db.setLockingEnabled(false);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cust_diet(" + "cd_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + "cust_id Integer,diet_id INTEGER,cd_validity DATE);");
        try {
            cur = db.query("tbl_diet",null,"type=?",new String[] {"Breakfast"}, null,null, null);
            cur.moveToFirst();
            while(!cur.isAfterLast())
            {
                    title = cur.getString(1);
                    descr = cur.getString(2);
                    form = cur.getString(6);
                    type = cur.getString(5);
                    calories = cur.getInt(3);
                    data.add(new Employer(title,"Calories : " + calories,"("+descr+")",form));
                    cur.moveToNext();
            }
            list.setAdapter(new EmployerArrayAdapter(this, data));

         cur.close();

        } catch (Exception u) {
            u.printStackTrace();
        }
        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int flag = 1;
                listItemCount = list.getCount();
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(cust+"aaaaaaaaaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaa"+list.getCount());
                cur = db.query("user_bmi",null,"cust_id=?",new String[]{cust}, null,null, null);
                System.out.println(cur.getCount()+"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                cur.moveToFirst();
                cal_needed = (Float.parseFloat(cur.getString(9)))*(0.25f);                      
                cur.close();
                System.out.println(cust+"bbbbbbb");
                tv_cal_needed.setText("you must not exceed "+ cal_needed +" calories");
                tv_cal_count.setText("calories of your selected diets are as follows : ");
                 for(int i=0; i<listItemCount; i++)
                {   TextView tv_name= (TextView) ((View)list.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                     TextView tv_calorie= (TextView) ((View)list.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
                 CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) ((View)list.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                 if(cbox.isChecked())
                  { tv_cal_str = tv_name.getText().toString(); 
                    cur = db.query("tbl_diet",null,"diet_title=?",new String[] {tv_cal_str}, null,null, null);
                    cur.moveToFirst();
                    temp_diet_id[counter]= cur.getInt(0);;
                    counter++;
                    tv_cal_count.append(tv_calorie.getText()+".");
                    System.out.println(cust+"cccccccc"+temp_diet_id[counter-1]);
                       System.out.println("not saved sill"+counter+"11111111111111111111111");
                     String temp_cal= tv_calorie.getText().toString().substring(11);
                      System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee11111111111111111111111");
                     float temp_calorie = Float.parseFloat(temp_cal);
                      System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee222222222222222222222222");
                        if(temp_calorie>cal_needed)
                        {  System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee3333333333333333333333333");
                            System.out.println(cust+"dddddddddd");
                            flag=0;

                        }
                  }
                 cur.close();
                  }

               System.out.println("not saved sill"+counter+"22222222222222222222");

                if(counter<=3 && counter>=1)
                {  
                    for(int i=0; i<listItemCount; i++)
                    {
                    CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) ((View)list.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    if(cbox.isChecked())
                         cbox.setChecked(false);
                    }
                final int temp_count = counter;
                       System.out.println("not saved sill"+counter+"3333333333333333333333");
                      if(flag==1){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BreakFast.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Do you want to save your BreakFast?")
                               .setCancelable(false)
                               .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                       System.out.println("not saved sill"+temp_count+"3333333333333333333333");
                                        for(int i=0; i<temp_count; i++)
                                                {
                                                    cur2 = db.query("user_bmi",null,"cust_id=? and bmi_active=?",new String[]{cust,"1"}, null,null, null);
                                                    cur2.moveToFirst();
                                                    System.out.println("not saved sill");
                                                    values.put("diet_id",temp_diet_id[i]);
                                                    values.put("cd_validity",cur2.getString(5));
                                                    values.put("cust_id",cust); System.out.println("saved");
                                                    db.insert("cust_diet", null, values);
                                                    cur.close();    
                                                    cur2.close();
                                                }   



                                                           tv_cal_count.setText("Your BreakFast has been saved");
                                                            tv_cal_needed.setText(null);
                                                           done.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                                     }
                               })
                               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                       for(int i=0; i<listItemCount; i++)
                                    {
                                    CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) ((View)list.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                                    if(cbox.isChecked())
                                         cbox.setChecked(false);
                                    } 
                                       dialog.cancel();
                                       tv_cal_count.setText(null);
                                   }
                               });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
                    }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BreakFast.this);
                            builder.setMessage("please select diet which do not exceed "+cal_needed+" calories!!!")
                                   .setCancelable(false)
                                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                                   {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                                       {
                                           tv_cal_count.setText(null);
                                           for(int i=0; i<listItemCount; i++)
                                           {
                                               CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) ((View)list.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                                               if(cbox.isChecked())
                                               cbox.setChecked(false);
                                            }
                                       }
                                   });

                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                            alert.show();

                        }
                        counter=0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tv_cal_count.setText(null);
                        Dialog mesg = new Dialog(BreakFast.this);
                        TextView text =  new TextView(BreakFast.this);
                        if(counter==0)
                        text.setText("plzz select some items but not more then three!!!");
                        else
                            text.setText("can't select more then three");
                        mesg.setContentView(text);

                        mesg.show();
                        counter=0;
                        for(int i=0; i<listItemCount; i++)
                        {
                        CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) ((View)list.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                        if(cbox.isChecked())
                             cbox.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }  



            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch block and post the stack trace.

Comment: plz be more specific i dont understand what u are trying to say......... please will u check what i am actually asking is ..

Comment: sir, i am getting error because iterating through the list view items is only limited to visible items when i try to get access to those which are not visible it gives null pointer exception as it do not find any view as it is not available to listview ....

Comment: i am using getcount method so that i get number of items present in adapter but not in listview so i get the error. now the problem is i want to access items which are not visible